# jQuery Simpleselect Plugin Event Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this Simpleselect plugin http://pioul.fr/jquery-simpleselect to style up a HTML select box. It simply hides the select element and replaces it with divs which can be easily styled. The issue I'm having is that I need to add an event listener to the select element which checks if it has been changed or not.

This is my code which works fine when I disable the Simpleselect plugin.

```
$("#mode").change(function() {
  console.log("changed mode");
  calcRoute();
});
```

The documentation has a paragraph about events towards the end of the page but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

This is the structure of the outputted HTML...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from example of developer http://jsfiddle.net/pioul/xn5yT/2/

```
$("select")
    .simpleselect()
    .bind("change.simpleselect", function(){
        console.log('change; new value='+ $(this).val());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation, you just have to pass the namespace of the plugin to the event (they change the element id by default):

```
$("#simpleselect_mode").change(function() {
  console.log("changed mode");
  calcRoute();
});
```

or you can bind to

```
$('#simpleselect_mode').bind('change.simpleselect', function() {
//Your code
});
```

Comment: I thought your first example would work too but it doesn't unfortunately. The second does if you simply change the selector to #mode rather than #simpleselect_mode. Thanks.